# send current element to ng-change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

I know in **jQuery** we can use `$(this)` in change event as example:

```
$('#id_element').change(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('unneeded-class');
});
```

**In AngularJS**, I have directive that has input as the following:

```
<input type="text" class="pull-left" placeholder="Name" ng-model="app.name" ng-change="textChanged()">
```

and in compile function I have the following:

```
scope.textChanged = function(){
}
```

I can't use `ng-class` to remove `unneeded` class, because this class was added by clicking on submit button, and I need when user start to type his name, I want to remove this class.

**My Directive to be more clear**

```
app.directive('appointment', function(RecursionHelper){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        appt: '=ngModel'
    },
    template:
        '<div class="row appointment-inputs">' +
            '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="pull-left" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="appt.f_name" ng-class="(appt.f_name === undefined || appt.f_name === \'\') ? \'empty\' : \'filled\'" ng-change="textChanged()">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="pull-left" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="appt.l_name" ng-class="(appt.l_name === undefined || appt.l_name === \'\') ? \'empty\' : \'filled\'" ng-change="textChanged()">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="pull-left app-input" placeholder="Appointment Date" ng-model="appt.date" name="date2" bs-datepicker data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" data-date-type="number" ng-class="(appt.date === undefined  || appt.date === \'\') ? \'empty\' : \'filled\'" ng-change="textChanged()">' +
            '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
    compile: function(element) {
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element, function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn){
        scope.textChanged = function(){
        }
      });
    }
};
});
```

And I add class call `red-border` for mandatory fields when user click on submit button, without type all mandatory field, I want when user start type on any field, fired `textChanged` function, and remove `red-border` class from current element only.

**My Question:**
How can I send the current element that has event to `textChanged` function ?

Comment: In angular you generally dont do it this way. You would just set the bindings in the view and update the model. So basically in your case you would just use **[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)** associated to some property on the scope and set or reset it.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, how do you get `unneeded-class` in the input? DO you set that in the view?

Comment: @PSL I know `ng-class`, but I need the element to do some operations on it as add attribute, and so on. And `unneeded-class` add to element by clicking on submit btn, so when the user type his name to text field, I need to remove this class

Comment: You may want to look at the directives then, if already available angular directives cannot do it for you.. For your specific scenariojust bind the class ("unneeded-class") with a model binding and set/reset it to add//remove it using ng-class

Comment: `I can't use ng-class to remove unneeded class, because this class was added by clicking on submit button,` That is because you are not adding the class the right way. It should indeed be using the angular bindings again. You have an X/Y problem you are trying to solve only a part of it which is caused by possible wrong way of implementation elsewhere

Comment: @PSL I agree with you, but I have more than input field in my directive, and all of these had `unneeded-class`, and I want to call one function for change event for them, If I used `ng-bind`, so I need to add special variable for each one of them !!, I think that'll be bad solution, but if I can use `this` in my event, I can do that in one line :)

Comment: `I have more than input field in my directive, and all of these had unneeded-class and I want to call one function for change event for them` How does it make it impossible to implement using angular bindings? And also if you are setting to track form dirty then there are specialized properties on the form input dirty you can use instead of even all these manually. But your question needs more context and code i believe

Comment: @PSL I edited my question, and added my directive

Comment: @MohamedYakout see my edited answer.  i will try to implement it in your directive also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve it by use the following:

```
angular.element(iElement[0].querySelector('.question-wrap')).removeClass('red-border');
```

Or, using `$broadcast`, and inject $rootScope to directive as the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('submitted:change', function () {
  if (!scope.answer) {
      scope.submitted = true;
  };
});
```

And fire  this action using the following:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('submitted:change', 'changed');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make a directive for ng-Change and put your doings

like

```
    app.directive('myChange', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.bind('change', function() {
     element.removeClass('unneeded-class'); // or something else
    });
  };
});
```

usage

```
  <input type="text" class="pull-left" placeholder="Name" ng-model="app.name" my-change>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is bad.. This is not angular way of doing things. Try using `ng-class`

Comment: which thing @PSL? $event itself is given by angular and angular.elment()

Comment: Both especially inside a controller, dom access/manipulations are supposedly should not be in a controller's context.

Comment: yes but to OP's answer that was the solution. Let me edit with some recomendations

Comment: That is because OPs issue could be an X/Y problem.

Comment: @A.B I got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`, so `$event` is undefined ?

Comment: @A.B Yeah but you dont need `{{` instead it could just be `{'unnneededclass':bclass}`and possibly the condition needs to be opposite i belive. i.e `ng-class="{'unnneededclass': !textEdited}"` and `$scope.textEdited = true` ?

Comment: @MohamedYakout i missed $() see now

Comment: I dont think you will get $event with ng-change

Comment: Thanks @PSL changed the {{}} , and textchange should remove unneededclass so it would we false on textchange() ?

Comment: @A.B See my last comment in the question and OPs question update. Seems like there is awhole lot of bigger problem which OP is trying to work around using this.

Comment: thanks @PSL i must remove this answer to further not to confuse him. as things are different i guess

Comment: @A.B Yeah. I guess we probably need more clarification and more code in the question. It is quite unclear now.. looks like.. :(